# Azure Functions - Precompiled C# function with TimerTrigger - TimerInfo class

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I want to have a precompiled Azure Function that is based off a timer trigger.

What nuget package do I need to install, or what dll do I need to reference to get access to the TimerInfo class? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 15):

`TimerInfo` is defined in package **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions** under namespace **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs**.

Comment: If this post helped you, please accept it as answered so it will help others.

Comment: More verbose answer:  as of WebJobs 2.0.0.0. You have to install the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions NuGet package.

TimerInfo shows up in the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs namespace after you reference Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions/lib/net45/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.dll